# how to use String as a Primary Key with Annotation in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: 
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.cihangir.model.Book] with root cause
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): 
com.cihangir.model.Book

```
package com.cihangir.model;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {



    @Id
    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false, unique=true)
    @Basic(optional=false)
    private String ISBN;
    private String bookTitle;
    private String category;
    private String author;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String ISBN, String bookTitle, String category, String author) {
        this.ISBN=ISBN;
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.category = category;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setISBN(String iSBN) {
        ISBN = iSBN;
    }

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    }
```

How can i fix it?Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for `String ISBN` as a primary key.

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "ISBN")
private String ISBN;
```

OR

You can create the `UUID` from Java like below code:

`UUID.randomUUID().toString();`